# jquery loading content from select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to load somethings in the page after a select input is selected.

**HTML**

```
<select id='select'>
    <option></option>
    <option>First Option</option>
    <option>Second Option</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#select').focusout(function(){
    alert("It worked");
});
```

However I can't find and event that does it. I tried with .focusout(), but it didn't work how I expected. The main idea is to put two select inputs, and load the options from the second one after the first is selected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#select').change(function(){
    alert("It worked");
});
```